# How to express complex derivatives in term of real variable

Tags: complex-analysis, partial-derivative

I'm studying complex analysis (mostly holomorphic functions) and after the proof of the Cauchy-Riemann equation in my book it's said that they can be expressed this way:
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + i\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} =0 
$$
Now, since it wants to show that this condition correspond to the fact that :
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar{z}} = 0
$$
it says that changing from the variables $x, y$ to the $z, \bar{z}$ ones results in:
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} =\frac{\partial}{\partial z} + \frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{z}}\qquad;\qquad\frac{\partial}{\partial y} = i \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial z} - \frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{z}}\right)
$$
and here I cannot understand how did he found the expression of the derivatives $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial}{\partial y}$ in terms of the partial derivarives of $\frac{\partial}{\partial z}, \frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{z}}$.

What are the mathematical step to reach this expression?

Comment: How did the author *define* $\frac\partial{\partial z}$ and $\frac\partial{\partial\overline z}$?

Comment: He did not, that's why I'm a little bit confused...

Comment: He used only the notation with the limit of the Difference quotient.